# wdContextMenu on left click

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

There is a nice hierarchical jQuery PlugIn for context-menus from web-delicious: [wdContextMenu](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdContextMenu/sample.htm). I want to use it on left clicks too, but I can't figure out how to do this (no button or which in the code, all bind-, click- and out-methods seem to do sth else).
Perhaps someone has done this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the line:

```
return $(this).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
```

to

```
return $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
```

Comment: Ha! You saved the day. Sometimes things are just too obvious ;) It's easy to puzzle beginners when the name of the plugin is also the name of an event. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After a quick walkthrough I don't think this is achievable because
this plugin uses oncontextmenu event and in the process of building up the menu component the click event(which is for the left click) is overridden for the elements to return false always.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking a look. I'll try to strip it down to just creating the menu.